# Removing rows in DF based on counting filtered data pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains ID & month of transaction.

I want to keep only the stores that have transactions in 12 months.

I tried first to filter by unique as follows:

```
df.groupby('STORE_NBR')['MONTH'].nunique()
```

I got from the code the store ID and the number of months. The problem is not all stores IDs appeared so I couldn't get them to drop.

sample of data :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g02al.png)

Comment: do you have some sample data? and sample expected output?

Comment: i have posted screen shot from the data frame in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('STORE_NBR').filter(lambda group: group['MONTH'].nunique() >= 12)
```